# SQL Query for data sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sorting

pls help me how to write sorting query.i have set of data  from my sql query like picture below

[image]

Current data sorting are order by level,sequence,chgcode. I want my data be appear by different sorting. 
which is if level = 2, the sorting will be 
[order by level,sequence,chgcode,date] 
other than that will be 
[order by level,sequence,date,chgcode]

The actual result that i need like picture below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky, but you can have multiple keys for the `order by`:

```
order by level, sequence,
         (case when level = 2 then chgcode end),
         (case when level = 2 then date end),
         date,
         chgcode
```

The first two keys are common for both groups.  The next two are specific for `level = 2` (and in that order); note that the value will be `NULL` for both when level is not 2.  The final two are for everything else.